# Kill a php browser request in Linux

Tags: php, linux

I have made a request to a PHP script through my browser to my apache web server. The script is downloading files from an FTP server and it is taking far too long. I think PHP has no timeout set on it so I need to find and kill this browser request.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: find its pid, issue `kill #` from the command line

Comment: How do I find its pid?

Comment: you command line access ?

Comment: I do yes, I know its something like `ps -ef | grep php` but I am pretty sure that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: `ps aux --sort=-pcpu,+pmem` i have htop installed so im not user the best one to use

Comment: I need to know the process id first before I can kill it... how do I do that? `ps aux --sort=-pcpu,+pmem` says unknown sort specifier

Comment: `ps aux | less` will list all running processes. Might want to do `ps aux | less | grep 'php'`

Comment: This shows only the process I just entered... yet the script is still running as new files are appearing... I am guessing that the process does not run as php if called by apache?

Comment: how about `ps -ef | grep php`

Comment: Just shows the one entry which is the ps command itself... I don't get why this is so hard to find...

Comment: did you run it as root? or you will only see the process of who you are logged in as

Answer (score 1):

you can kill the process from the command line if you have root (sudo) access

the running php process will appear as a web server, httpd or apache2.  Look for the one that was created the right time ago -- the oldest is the parent process that forks the workers, you want the one that's running the script and not the parent.  Ps shows the process creation time and accumulated cpu time, use that to find the right one (I use `ps aux | grep apache2`, but I'm more used to the BSD toolchain)  The ps output includes columns START (process start time, hrs:mins or MonDate) and TIME (cpu time used, min:sec)

```
% ps aux | grep apache2
root      2641  0.0  0.1  74048 14468 ?        Ss   Feb12   0:27 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
www-data  2913  0.0  0.0  74120  6656 ?        S    Feb12   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
andras   32069  0.0  0.0   3560  1792 pts/8    S+   20:57   0:00 grep apache2
www-data 32506  0.0  0.0  74120  6656 ?        S    Feb14   0:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

I configured apache to start only 2 worker processes.  The one owned by `root` is the master, `www-data` are the workers.  The column headings are

```
% ps aux | head -1
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
```

You can kill it with any killing signal, but -15 (-TERM) is the usual.

Php does have a default 30-second cpu usage timeout, but an ftp transfer uses very little cpu.

Comment: When I do `ps aux | grep apache2` I get
`wwwrun   20651  0.0  0.6 117468 12520 ?        S    Feb20   0:04 /usr/sbin/httpd2-prefork -f /etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

Comment: look for httpd too, `ps aux | grep httpd`.  Looks like on your system the web server is called `httpd2-prefork` while on mine it's `apache2`  There should be several processes.